# Wifi error when using a modified galaxy tab kernel

Tags: android, linux-kernel, galaxy-tab, rooted-device

I know that xda-developers forum may be the ideal place to ask such questions, but I haven't had a chance to find the answer there or by extensive searching around the web.

**Preliminaries:** I'm doing a research on the Android kernel. So I have installed a rooted rom on Galaxy Tab 10 wifi and used a modified Samsung kernel source code to implement my modifications of the kernel. I successfully installed and tested the kernel but...

**Problem**: The tab works with no problems. The only issue is "wifi error"; it can't communicate with the wireless card. Definitely a driver issue. I have not touched any parts of the kernel regarding wireless communications.

**My thoughts**: I think I'll only need to install the wifi device driver. My problem is that I cannot find the driver. Where should I look for it? Is it going to be part of the build kernel?

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I found it after lots of searching! I wish these things could be documented better. I had to include the built Wi-Fi driver module in my update.zip file and apply the update and finally restart. The driver was built under

```
drivers/net/wireless/bcm4330/dhd.ko
```

Now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong WiFi Kernel modules for your installed kernel.

If you built the kernel from source, then you should be able to build the kernel modules too and install them into the ROM.

The modules must be built by the same system and from the same source tree else the kernel will not load them.

Comment: I understand this. My point is that I don't know where to look for the wifi drivers in the source code. I have already built a bunch of drivers when I built the kernel.